# Fatal error when converting pdf to png

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript.net

I'm trying to convert a pdf into a PNG, using the code given in the following example (the first function) : https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/DeviceUsageSample.cs

However, I get this error on launch : " An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -100"... which doesn't mean a lot.

How comes this basic example doesn't work ? I downloaded the latest Ghostscript.NET.dll here : https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/ and added it to the references of the project. My OS is Windows 7 x32 bits and I run VisualStudio as an administrator.

Here is my code :

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GhostscriptPngDevice devPNG = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.Png256);
    devPNG.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    devPNG.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    devPNG.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(96, 96);
    devPNG.InputFiles.Add(@"D:\Public\FOS.pdf");
    devPNG.OutputPath = @"D:\Public\FOS.png";
    devPNG.Process();
}
```

Comment: maybe it's a bug inside library ?

Comment: @Disappointed Maybe it is. Besides referencing the Ghostscript.NET.dll in the project and calling it at the start, there is no other requirement right ? In that case what do you suggest I do ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried replacing the path of the input and output by one **without any space** and it now works ! Here is the code I ended up using :

```
using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int desired_x_dpi = 96;
    int desired_y_dpi = 96;

    string inputPdfPath = @"D:\Public\temp\rasterizer\FOS.pdf";
    string outputPath = @"D:\Public\temp\rasterizer\output\";

    using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
    {
        rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath);
        for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
        {
            var pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, string.Format("Page-{0}.png", pageNumber));
            var img = rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
            img.Save(pageFilePath + "ImageFormat.Png");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace any character strange (non alpanumeric and spaces, keep filepath "clean" and in shared/temp folder to grant access to any user/process and should work just fine